# How can NASM Assembly generate a dynamically sized char array to send to C++?

Tags: memory-management, assembly, nasm

I have to create a NASM Assembly function that will return `char` array to C++.

This can be done easily by first reserving some space for the vector:

```
SECTION .bss
  myArray: resb 255 ; Reserved 255 bytes for my array
```

Then filling up `myArray`, adding `0` to define the end of the `char` array and then returning the pointer of `myArray` to C++.

As you can see, it is fairly possible that my generated array will be smaller than 255 bytes. Or even worse, maybe it will be bigger.

How can I generated a byte array by reserving only the necessary amount of bytes?

Another obstacle is that the only moment I *know* the size of the resulting array is only when it has been fully constructed - that is, at the very end of the function.

Comment: `sys_brk` will be your friend in this case.

Comment: Are you talking about `std::vector`? In that case I'm pretty sure the C++ code won't like it if you just pass it a pointer to an array of bytes.

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, I meant array. I will fix it.

Comment: Call `malloc` by assembly?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the pointer will work correctly using the "delete" operator of C++ you'll have to call the same function that C++ will use to allocate arrays. This may be "malloc" or another memory allocation function.

C++ uses a wrapper function that calls this memory allocating function like this:

```
_operator_new_generic:
    jmp malloc
```

Unfortunately the name of this wrapper function (here: _operator_new_generic) differs from C++ compiler to C++ compiler (Microsoft uses different names than GNU).

Another possibility would be always to use "malloc" and not to use the "delete" operator but "free()" to release the array later.